# ngif issue in a nav bar

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, navbar

Good morning, I'm working on Angular project where the nav buttons are stored in a `firestore` collection.

Here's my html :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
            data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
            aria-expanded="false" 
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a mat-button class="companyName" routerLink="/">
            <span>
                <img src="../../../assets/images/nav/synergielogo.jpg"> 
            </span>
        </a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="dossiers" *ngFor="let d of ongletservice.dossiers">
                <button mat-raised-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1"> 
                    {{d.titre}}
                </button>
            </ul>
            <ul *ngFor="let s of ongletservice.solo">
                <button id='btn-1' 
                    mat-raised-button routerLink="/{{s.lien}}">
                    {{s.titre}}
                </button>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='menu'>
            <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
                <div *ngFor="let d of ongletservice.dossiers" class='menu'>
                    <div *ngFor="let dd of ongletservice.dropdowns">
                        <div> 
                            <button *ngIf="dd.dossier===d.titre" 
                                id='btn-2' mat-button 
                                routerLink="../../{{dd.lien}}">
                              {{dd.titre}}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-menu>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

For some reason the `ngIf` in the `mat-menu` isn't working so if I have more than one dropdown button, it will get all the buttons that are in one dropdown, not just the ones that are linked to it.

All the rest is working fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for reading.

Comment: It seems to as if youre not using the correct directive on the button in the menu. You will have to mark them with "mat-menu-item" as you can read here: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<ng-container/>` and avoid nested ngFor:

```
<mat-menu #menu1="matMenu">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let o of ongletservice" class='menu'>
       <div> 
          <button *ngIf="o.dropdowns.dossier===o.dossiers.titre" 
                   id='btn-2' mat-button 
                   routerLink="../../{{o.dropdowns.lien}}">
                   {{o.dropdowns.titre}}
          </button>
       </div>     
   </ng-container>
</mat-menu>
```